# Can I map contrl and hyphen <C-->?

Tags: vimrc, key-bindings

How can I map Ctrl and hyphen key? Usually when mapping Ctrl key with other keys there is a hypen key in the middle. But I would like to use this hypen key as my mapping, can I do that?

When I tap Ctrl and Hyphen key I would like the vim doing the horizontal splits. (The vertical splits in my setting are Ctrl and backslash, therefore it make sense for me to do the horizontal vertical like so.)

Comment: http://vimhelp.appspot.com/vim_faq.txt.html#faq-20.5

Comment: You can't map certain combinations. Try any alphanumerical letter. m is pretty close to the hyphen for example.